# How to install IPv6 on Windows 2003

Tags: windows, ipv6

How do you install IPv6 on Windows 2003 ... **and get it working ?**

I'm trying to add IPv6 to one of my development machines which is Windows 2003. I've followed the knowledge base article on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325449), and added the **Microsoft TCP/IP version 6** protocol, but the next section on manually configuring IPv6 has got me baffled ... on my other development machines are Windows 7 or Windows 2008, and they didn't need any manual configuration of IPv6, it just worked out-of-the-box

Comment: Microsoft 2003 is based on Windows XP which does not support IPv6 "Out of Box" like Windows Vista and Windows 7 Server editions do [ Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2 ].  So you have to manually configure the IPv6 address.

Comment: @Ramhound: Manual configuration is not necessary; both XP and Server 2003 support stateless autoconfig. Only manual *installation* of IPv6 protocol is needed. (On the other hand, most services, including Terminal Services and the whole Active Directory stack, *weren't written* to use IPv6 at all...)

Comment: @grawity I've manually installed the protocol, but even after a reboot of the virtual machine, it doesn't have an IPv6 address, so how/when is the auto-config meant to happen ??

Comment: @SteveC: Is your network using stateless autoconfiguration or DHCPv6? Both are activated automatically on boot, but Server 2k3 only supports autoconf, *not* DHCPv6. If autoconf is in use on the network, you can use Wireshark and `netsh interface ipv6 renew` to see whether Windows attempts it or not.

Comment: @grawity This is getting beyond me ... network is VMware virtual's running on laptop Win7x64, with I think the DHCP coming from our home broadband router

Comment: @SteveC: If IPv6 is configured using DHCPv6, then you might have to use "Dibbler DHCPv6" in the VM (probably best way), or set up the laptop to advertise an IPv6 subnet using stateless autoconfiguration (can be done but not recommended, especially on laptops).